# Converting 12 hour format to 24 hour without timezone in R

Tags: r, datetime

I've tried using strptime and as.Date to convert a 12 hour format to 24 hour but I'm getting NA for both. I'm not sure where the issue is

```
as.Date("3/23/2017 3:10:36 PM", format="%m/%d/%y  %I:%M:%S %p")
strptime("3/23/2017 3:10:36 PM","%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

Any pointers to help me out? Preferably without a timezone appended

Comment: You need `%Y` not `%y` for four-digit years

Comment: Now I feel silly for asking this quetion :| But that was precisely the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use

```
x <- strptime("3/23/2017 3:10:36 PM", format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

(With capital %Y for 4-digit year) And then

```
format(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

To get a 24-h format character string without time zone.